# Defining factor groups, $\Bbb{R}/2\pi\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Simple question but would like clarification. I know the set of cosets of a normal subgroup can be made into a group called a factor group. And with $H$ being a normal subgroup of $G$, $G/H = \{aH | a \in G\}$ is a group.

How do we define $ℝ/2πℤ$? $ℝ/ℤ$?
For the first example, I understood it as $H = \{2π, 4π, 6π, 8π, 10π, ..\}$ and the factor group being $ℝ/2πℤ = \{aH | a \in ℝ\}$ = ℝ.

Can we say $ℝ/2πℤ$ is equivalent to all multiples of $2\pi$. Just looking for a way to understand this better to use in a proof I'm working on.

Comment: $2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of all integer multiples of $2\pi$, so including $2 \pi, 4 \pi, 6 \pi, \dots $ but also including $0, - 2\pi, -4\pi, \dots$ (or else it wouldn't be a subgroup). $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, it has torsion while $\mathbb{R}$ is torsion-free), it's isomorphic to a group called the circle group $S^1$. Other than that, I don't really understand your question: you say you know the definition of $G/H$ but ask what is the definition of $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$...?

Comment: So the factor group is all real numbers multiplied by the set of integer multiples of $2\pi$? Just wanted clarification on what the factor group exactly is, think I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: No. It's the set of cosets of $2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$. For $r \in \mathbb{R}$ the corresponding coset is the set $\{ r + 2 \pi k : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. For example, when $r = \pi$ the coset is $\{ \dots - 3\pi, - \pi, \pi, 3 \pi, \dots \}$. The "multiplication" in the notation $aH$ refers to the group operation in $G$, and for $\mathbb{R}$ the group operation is addition.

Comment: Not multiplied, summed with. Your group operation is addition. An element in the factor group is a real number "plus" all multiples of $\mathbb{Z}$, or $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ in your other example. So for example in the factor group $0$ and $1$ are identified because $0+\mathbb{Z}$ contains $1$. This periodicity gives rise to the circle.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! Thanks for the help. Got a last question asking whether $ℝ/2πℤ$ is isomorphic to $ℝ/ℤ$. I understand they're both isomorphic to the circle group but how do we know (intuitively at least) that they're isomorphic to each other? Is there a simple map that we just define between the two?

Comment: The map is multiplication by $2\pi$.